# Why do some JSF components stop carrying out partial processing/rendering?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In one form, I have a checkbox whose options effectively carry out filtering of a PrimeFaces data table in another form:

```
     <h:form id="mainForm">
          <!-- some other code here -->
          <p:selectManyCheckbox id="..." value="#{Bean.eventTypeFilters}" >
               <p:ajax listener="#{ManagedBean.applyEventTypeFilters}" update="form:DataTable" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Access" itemValue="Access" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Execution" itemValue="Execution" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Lambda" itemValue="Lambda" />
          </p:selectManyCheckbox>     
     </h:form>
```

When I check or uncheck an option above, the data table automatically updates itself to reflect it, and the function detailed in the listener attribute within the p: ajax tag is carried out.

The code of the method in the backing bean:

```
    public void applyEventTypeFilters() {
        System.out.println("APPLY EVENT TYPE FILTERS START");
        List<Log> newFilteredLogs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Log l : allLogs) {
            if (eventTypeFilters.contains(l.getEventType()) && (apiFilter == null || l.getApi().equals(apiFilter))) {
                newFilteredLogs.add(l);
            }
        }
        filteredLogs = newFilteredLogs;
        System.out.println("APPLY EVENT TYPE FILTERS END");
    }
```

Here is the JSF code of the data table:

```
<h:form id="secondForm">
     <p:dataTable id="DataTable" widgetVar="DataTable" value="#{Bean.filteredLogs}" var="log" rowKey="#{log.logId}" 
     rows="10" paginator="true" 
     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50">

          <p:column headerText="Extended Request Id" sortBy="#{log.extendedRequestId}" filterBy="#                                                            
          {log.extendedRequestId}" >
                     <h:outputText value="#{log.extendedRequestId}" />
          </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

However, whenever I type in the filter input box in as detailed above, and then check or uncheckout an option in the checkbox detailed in the 1st code block, the data table stops automatically updating itself, but from the server logs I still see that the server-side method upon checking/unchecking is called.

My question is: How do I ensure that the capacity for partial processing/rendering of the 1st checkbox component remains even when I am also simultaneously making use of other such capacities in another component(in this case the filter)?

Also, I believe that when filtering the table, there is a list which is automatically created containing the filtered objects. How do I gain more direct control over this list?

Thanks a great deal!

Comment: There probably is an error in your browser's JavaScript console. Please share its contents.

Comment: Apologies, but I don't know what you mean. I am developing using NetBeans 12.4 and the GlassFish server, and at no point have I written any JavaScript code.

Comment: I was not implying you did. Please press F12 in your browser and share any errors.

Comment: First thing I can spot is that it's doing `update="form:DataTable"` rather than `update="secondForm:DataTable"`. Referencing a non-existing component should be giving you an error though.

Comment: @Jasper de Vries : Apologies for the severely delayed reply: I opened the console, and there were no errors whatsoever.
@ Adam Waldenberg : Oh, that's a mistake in editing I made to anonymize my code - there is no discrepancy in names/ids in the actual code.